# Nonblocking ncurses: prevent stdout

Tags: c++, linux, stdout, ncurses, suppression

#### what I am trying to do and the problem

I am trying to use nonblocking ncurses getch() and output data to stdout. The problem is that cnurses also writes to stdout. It writes `[?1l>[?1h=[17;1H[?1049l[23;0;0t` tens of thousands of times.

#### What I have tried

I tried the answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371877/ncurses-and-linux-pipeline) similar question, however I need to use the `nodelay`-function which only allows WINDOWs but not SCREENs.

I tried to temporarely disable stdout with two solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30184998/how-to-disable-cout-output-in-the-runtime), however it had no effect

#### source code

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int get_input(void)
{
    WINDOW *w = initscr();
    raw();
    nodelay(w, TRUE);
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
    cbreak();
    noecho();
    int input = getch();
    endwin();
    return input;
}
int main(){
    while(true){
        int input = get_input();
        if(input != -1){
            cout<<input;
            exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

compile on linux with `g++ -lncurses file.cpp`

Comment: Usually with ncurses, you init the ncurses system once, you use ncurses throughout your program for both input and output, and when done you end ncurses and end your program.  This code has the init-use-end in a loop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ncurses and Linux pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371877/ncurses-and-linux-pipeline)