# Python3 curses code not working in pipeline

Tags: python, python-3.x, curses

I am writing a python script that I want to use in a unix pipeline. My goal is to write to the screen using curses (which should only be seen by the person running the command, not the pipe), and then write the "return value" to stdout at the end so it can continue down the pipeline, something along the lines of `./myscript.py | consumer_script`

This was failing in mysterious ways until I found [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371877/ncurses-and-linux-pipeline). The suggested solution was to use newterm instead of init_scr.

My problem is that I am using python, and from what I could find in the documentation, newterm doesnt exist. All I was able to find was a single reference to newterm, and it didn't come with a link.

Could someone please either point me towards the python newterm, or suggest another way of working with pipes and curses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're making this more complicated than it needs to be... the simple answer is to write the curses stream to another handle than stdout. If it works for you, stderr is the obvious choice. In short, anything that gets written to stdout goes into the pipeline, and if you don't want it there, you need a different handle.

Check out this thread for ways to write to stderr in python:
[How to print to stderr in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574702/how-to-print-to-stderr-in-python)

Comment: All of those suggestions seem to be ways to print directly to stderr, however as I am using curses I don't have that level of control. stdscr.addstr doesnt allow you to specify an output stream line print does, and using sys.stderr.write would defeat the point of using curses in the first place.